# css Keyframes from & to

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I found this code pen for eye blinking animations in css. but i don't understand why they have used 0%,100% and 5%,95% like this. can anyone explain me why is it like this? tho changing these values affects the speed of animation.

```
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .face {
         display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          width: 150px;
          height: 200px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: tomato;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
     }

.face:hover {
    background: green;
}

.eye {
    background: white;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: blink 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: scale(1, .05);
    }
    5%,
    100% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Here is the codepen link as well: https://codepen.io/obaidnadeem/pen/rNwWexx

Answer (score 0):

this 0%, 100%, 5% and again 100% are the propetries of the animated keyframes. Only those kayframes will be animated. More on it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Answer (score 0):

The first 100% in the code given is redundant as the second overrides it.

In the 95% case though the first 100% is not redundant. These settings alter the timing as you point out.

The time the eyes are open (scale y is 1) is slightly shorter and the time taken to blink (move from scale 1 to 0.5 and back) is slightly longer and the opening and closing times are the same.

Comment: I forgot to explain properly that the 95% version ensures that the eyes close in the same amount of time as the 0 to 5% whereas if it goes straight to 100% the eyes close instantly with no transition.